# Thunderbird won't download some emails

Tags: email, thunderbird, download

Because of some frustrations with Mac Mail, I switched to Thunderbird which I've used in the past.

Unfortunately, it only downloads some of the emails. If I check on the server, there are still emails waiting to be downloaded. If I open Mail, it will download all the email. But Thunderbird won't do it.

In an attempt to solve the problem, I have turned off all junk mail controls in both the server and local folder settings for Thunderbird. But I still can't get them.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to delete your .msf files after backing up your profile. Details are here:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2623631

In short, "First backup your profile -- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup but do not compact folders as recommended in that link.
Close Thunderbird and navigate to your Profile Folder ( http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Folder ). Find the files with the extension msf, such as Inbox.msf. Note that there will be sets of two files with the name but only one of these will have the MSF extension. Delete the files with the MSF extension. Restart Thunderbird, compact all folders, and see if things are back to normal. Note that the MSF files do NOT contain your messages. They are, for lack of a better term, an index file and will be recreated by Thunderbird as required."

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that this afternoon when I have a few moments to breathe. Then I'll post feedback.